# make button enabled when input field is correct using Watermark

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, watermark

Is it possible to change a button from disabled to enabled once the value in the input field is correct

I have this form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
     <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="Email" class="form-text" />
     <input id="bt_login_signup" type="submit" value="Sign in" class="bt_login"/>
}
```

I want the submit button to be enabled only once the email entered is correct. Is it possible to use watermark to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure ASP.NET MVC supports this out of the box, although you could certainly write some Javascript to do it (disable to begin with, check the text after each keyup event on the text box).

But why don't you use the normal MVC Model validation?  If the user submits invalid info, the error messages you configure appear next to each field ...

Comment: Yes I know it's weired, but but my boss wants the submit button to be disabled until the email address is valid and he wants me to use Watermark for that. What I want to know, is it possible ?

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by Watermark in this context.  That normally refers to the placeholder text that sits in a text box before you enter anything, like "Enter your email address".  What does that have to do with disabling the submit button?

Comment: So if I understand well, Watermak is not used to this kind of things (I mean enabling a button when a certain validation is verified)